# Set All Values the same in Gridview item template field(Dropdown)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Ok,so I know the title is not great but I will try and explain.

I have a gridview with a dropdown in it as a template field. I want to have it so that if someone selects something in the dropdown the all of the dropdowns in the gridview get changed to that value. This is what i am thinking but see the comment:

```
protected void dcDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (recPartDdl.SelectedItem.Text != "All")
        {
           string value = //Need to get the value of the changed drop down.

            foreach(GridViewRow row in allRmaGv.Rows)
            {
                DropDownList dcDropDown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("dcDdl");
                dcDropDown.SelectedValue = value;

            }
        }
    }
```

I need to do this for an excel like filter in a gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter out the row type when looping through the rows in the GridView so you do not try to look for the control in the header rows and/or footer rows, so try this inside your `foreeach` loop:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in allRmaGv.Rows)
{
    // Try to find the `dcDdl` in data rows only, because they do not exist in header or footer rows
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList dcDropDown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("dcDdl");
        dcDropDown.SelectedValue = value;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

To get the value of the selected dropdown's value, do this:

```
protected void dcDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (recPartDdl.SelectedItem.Text != "All")
    {
        string value = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString();

        foreach(...)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is not the question though. The question is how do I assign the value of my variable value? it needs to be the value of the selected item.

Comment: I think i figured it out, I am going to try it at work tomorrow at work and see if it works. I am planning on using a command argument on the drop down control that passes the row index to the code behind.

Comment: Oh sorry did not see that part, but the only checking data rows is still pertinent. See UPDATE in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    protected void dcDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (recPartDdl.SelectedItem.Text != "All")
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

            //First check type of ddl.SelectedValue and then process
            string value = ddl.SelectedValue;

            foreach(GridViewRow row in allRmaGv.Rows)
            {
                DropDownList dcDropDown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("dcDdl");
                dcDropDown.SelectedValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
```